# Unix strip EOF (not EOL/whitespace) from stream in pipe

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a program which takes input and standard input until eof is given (CTRL-D on linux). I want to run this program with a lot of default input, then continue entering things until I manually hit CTRL-D to stop it. Is there any way to remove the EOF that a bash pipeline puts in?

IE: `cat somedata.dat | <insert answer here> | ./myprogram` such that `myprogram` never receives EOF on stdin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash doesn't actually add an "end-of-file" character; there isn't such a thing. Rather, the problem is that `./myprogram` reaches the end of its standard input (which is hooked up to the pipe), so the next time it tries to read a character, it gets end-of-file instead. There's no way to have it suddenly switch over to "stealing" the standard input from the terminal, because it's not hooked up to that input at all.

Instead, to feed more input to `./myprogram` than just what's in `somedata.dat`, you can ask `cat` to start reading (and forwarding) its own standard input after it's finished reading `somedata.dat`:

```
cat somedata.dat - | ./myprogram
```

or

```
cat somedata.dat /dev/stdin | ./myprogram
```

**Edited to add** (per further question in the comments): If you have a more complicated pipeline feeding into `./myprogram`, rather than just a file, then you can run your main command and *then* `cat`, piping the whole thing to `./myprogram`:

```
{
  reallyConfusingTransform < somedata.dat
  cat
} | ./myprogram
```

or in one line:

```
{ reallyConfusingTransform < somedata.dat ; cat ; } | ./myprogram
```

(Note that I've also eliminated a "useless use of `cat`" (UUOC), but if you really prefer to use `cat` that way, you can still write `cat somedata.dat | reallyConfusingTransform` instead of `reallyConfusingTransform < somedata.dat`.)

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I wanted. I guess that does make sense too, a program can't just "not produce an EOF". The best it can do is start piping stdin to stdout manually. Is there an in-stream version that will work though? EG: `cat somedata.dat | reallyConfusingTransform | something | ./myprogram` perhaps some kind of argument to tee or a similar utility?

Comment: @LambdaBeta: Not in quite that form, but yes. I've added a bit to my answer.